# Is there a way to set build preference on Launchpad?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, bazaar

Say, for example, I am solving a problem for someone.  I know they are on x64.  Is there a way to set the build preference to x64 before x86?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set the build preference to x64 before x86?

Well, AFAIK builds are scheduled in parallel, it just depends on where you are in the queue (x86_64 is typically more backed up than i386). If you wish to build an *Architecture-All* package *only* for x64, then you can simply modify the `debian/control` file, changing all instances of `Architecture: all` to `Architecture: amd64`; that way no i386 build will take place.

If you really need something built *now*, you could also change the `urgency` in the changelog to jump ahead in the queue, but one has to be mindful about misuse if this is purely a personal-type PPA build :)  IMO I would simply `dpkg-buildpackage` it if this was a one-off thing.